# Push upgrade for unlocked packages

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, push-upgrade

In packaging 2.0 model when we release unlocked package, is there any way to deliver it to a bunch of clients at once, i.e. something similar to push upgrade used in classic packaging model?
Or should we just ask clients to install/upgrade package manually by providing them url or make new version available on AppExchange?

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now possible since Winter 21
see https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_sfdx_packaging_push_upgrade_2GP.htm

What you need is to insert and update some records in your DevHub and Salesforce will push upgrades (for a specific package/version) for all or a subset of your subscribers.

Follow this page to do this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/push_upgrade_intro_2GP.htm

I have developed a visual force that you can push in your devhub to see the list of subscribers --> https://github.com/VinceFINET/MySubscribers
I am working on a little button (on this VF page) to push easily upgrades... but not yet there!!

Comment: What about security review - is this a precondition to be able to use push upgrade for unlocked packages or unlocked packages are not subject of security review at all?

Comment: ^ second this. It seems like with Unlocked Packages the benefit for an org is that they can then push upgrades to their clients more iteratively and not get subjected to security review each time